# Capturing onClick on iframe video in react

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I have a custom wrapper component

```
<wrapperC>
    <iframe title='abc' width='600' height='415' src={`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKjk0ECXjiQ?autoplay=0`} allowFullScreen />
</wrapperC>
```

I am not able to find a way to capture an onClick event in the  if someone clicks on the video play button.

```
onClick = () => {
    alert('clicked');
}

render() {
    const {
        children
    } = this.props;

    return (
        <div>
            <SomeOtherComponent onEnter={this.onEnter} onLeave={this.onLeave}>
                {React.cloneElement(children, { onClick: this.onClick })}
            </SomeOtherComponent>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Can someone suggest me a way to capture the click event on the iframe video which will also let me play video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a wrapper component which wraps the google you tube library. This library renders an iframe and gives access to video life events.

Comment: This sounds really useful! I am trying to figure out how to do this, and I am somewhat of a beginner. I'm trying to capture timeUpdate, play, and pause events of a video that is embedded with iframe.  Would you be willing to share your code!? It would be super helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a such problem when was working with custom video-player, which actually is an iframe. I ended up with wrapper. At the end it looked like:

```
<div style={{
position: 'relative'
}}
 onClick={() => {
   console.log('hello'); //add your code here
 }}
>
  <div
  style={{
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    'z-index': 100,
  }}
  }/>
  <iframe/> //you could use your custom React component which are iframe under the hood
</div>
```